# Laravel wrong passwords accepted

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

Debian 11, Laravel 8, Breeze Auth
If my password is "12345678" any password where first 8 characters are correct is accepted.  if password is >8 character, only 8 characters matter. If password is <8 character, behavior is OK
for example
(1)
123456 Fail
1234567 Fail
12345678 Successful (correctly stored)
1234567890 Successful

(2)
123456 Fail
1234567 Fail
12345678 Successful
1234567890 Successful (correctly stored)

(3)
123456 Fail
1234567 Fail
1234567 Successful (correctly stored)
12345678 fail

Comment: Please show your auth controller (or however you're testing the passwords), and exactly what you mean.

Comment: You're likely using `crypt()` with a two-character salt, resulting in use of the old (and insecure) `CRYPT_STD_DES` algorithm, which only looks at the first eight characters of input. Probably a setting in your config somewhere -- was this updated from an older version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
while testing, I used to create user directly in mysql using `encrypt()` in SQL statement
in PHP it is `password_hash('xyz',PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`
So, password created by mysql SQL statement were insecure
But, password created by php script were secure.

Comment: mysql encrypt is same as unix crypt(), it can be verified by php password_verify, with 8 character limitation. mysql password() can not be verified by php password_verify(). So, using php password_hash('xyz',PASSWORD_BCRYPT) and verifying it in php using password_verify() is best. mysql functions should not be used for creating passwords.